# What kind of transformation Trunks used in Dragon Ball Super when fighting Vegeta?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In episode 54 of Dragon Ball Super (original air date, August 7):

> Trunks uses some kind of transformation. After transformed SSJ2, his hair grows, electricity sparks disappear, and his muscles grow. It looks similar to the USSJ (Super Saiyan 1 third grade) but now he has short hair, so could his hair grows like if he were transforming into a SSJ3? Is this a kind of new transformation or what?

Comment: You just posted a question on an episode that came out a few hours ago. Please use the spoiler markup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it was the fondly nicknamed Super (or ultra) transformation. The wiki calls it the [Second](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Second_Grade) Grade and [Third](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Third_Grade) Grade. It is simply turning power into Muscle mass, which greatly enhances strength, but the bulk lowers speed. Vegeta, Trunks, and Goku learned and used this transformation in the Cell Saga. Vegeta and Trunks specifically used this to beat down Cell in his second form, before Vegeta helped him obtain 18 and get his perfect form.

Comment: yeah, I was watching some youtubers and they seem to agree with that. Weird his hair grows though

Comment: @Pablo Indeed, It seems to be a general trait of most Sayian power ups, the hair becomes spikier.

Comment: Note however that only Trunks used this form fully. Vegeta knew from the beginning that putting all your Ki into strength while neglecting speed was useless.